# Java code to publish json message on multiple threads for load testing

Tags: java, multithreading

I need help in writing java code to publish json message on multiple threads for load testing . I have my publish function written to POST the message , but how to use this POST for multiple threads .for e.g I need to publish 1000 messages on 10 threads . WorkerCount = 1000 and ThreadCount = 10 .

Comment: Please post the code you've already written.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: public HttpResponse HttpClientPost(String url, String username, String passcode, String payload) throws JsonGenerationException, 
     JsonMappingException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException,
        CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, AuthenticationException {   
     SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
          .loadTrustMaterial(null, (certificate, authType) -> true).build();
    }         
} .............for e.g above is my POST function just copied the paramters passed , so I need to pass payload for load test

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TestNG framework in a client-side testing project.

Say you want to test with 3 users that have an id, password and name (your input may not be users, but you get the idea):

```
@DataProvider(name = "users", parallel = true)
public Object[][] users() {
    return new Object[][] { 
        { "123", "pwd1", "Charlie Parker" },
        { "234", "pwd2", "Sonny Stitt" }, 
        { "345", "pwd3", "Julian Adderley" }
    };
}
```

, and you want to call your POST method across a pool of 5 available threads and do this 100 times (i.e. 300 invocations):

```
@Test(dataProvider = "users", 
      priority = 1,
      description = "Call my POST method for the users in the dataProvider", 
      threadPoolSize = 5, 
      invocationCount = 100)
    public void stressTestMyPOSTMethod(String id, String pwd, String name) { 
       ...
       call post method (using e.g. RestAssured) with the user variables
       ...
```

Comment: thanks , I got this but I have written code to pass multiple json objects to my POST method but how to run it in multiple threads . In short I need code to run throuh multiple threads